# Webpack file-loader (multiple path)

Tags: javascript, html, image, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I'm using Webpack in a project which is supposed to be recovered by another dev.

In my configuration, I use `file-loader` to process my `.png/jpg/svg` files.

```
{
     test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
     use: [
          {
               loader: 'file-loader',
               options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: './assets/images'
               }
          }
     ]
}
```

The thing is that I'd like to have the same arborescence in my `dist/` folder than in my `src/` `(assets > images > folderName)`

```
> src
  - assets
       - images
            - icons
            - logos
            - ...
```

For now, every images are in the same `assets/images` folder.

Using `[path]` output this structure (which contains the `src/` folder):

```
> dist       
     - src
         - assets
             - images
                 - icons
                 - logos
                 - ...
```

Any idea of how define the root folder only for images assets?

Thanks in advance